# 'pip install -e' gives error with project name "yolov3"

Tags: python, installation, pip, dependencies, python-module

I have installed a couple of dependencies in editable state using `pip install -e path/to/project`, using the command parameter `-e` for the first time today.

For the first dependency, the project `sort`, everything worked perfectly.

But for the other dependency, the project `yolov3` things didn't work out as fine, although I have used the same exact commands:

To installation

```
(torch) user@user-PC:~/Code/Project$ pip install -e Detection/yolov3/
```

To check

```
(torch) user@user-PC:~/Code/Project$ pip show yolov3
Name: yolov3
Version: 1.0
Summary: UNKNOWN
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /home/user/Code/Project/Detection/yolov3
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

To use

```
from sort import Sort    
from yolov3 import get_detections_from_single_frame as get_detections

dummy_frame = None    
mot_tracker = Sort()    
track_bbs_ids = mot_tracker.update(get_detections(dummy_frame))
```

But I get an error as

```
(torch) user@user-PC:~/Code/Project$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from yolov3 import get_detections_from_single_frame as get_detections
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yolov3'
```

I have tried to change the name to **yolo** to eliminate the number in the module name and it did not work, but I might have failed to change the project name itself.

Here is the setup.py that I am using for the project yolov3 (I am using the same for sort, except for the name property for obvious reasons):

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='yolov3', version='1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

Here is the [project structure](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3):

```
yolov3/
├── __init__.py
├── models/
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── liba1.py
|   ├── liba2.py
|   ├── liba3.py
├── utils/
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── libb1.py
|   ├── libb2.py
|   ├── libb3.py
└── weights/
    └──  libc1.py
```

Could someone please tell me what am I missing?

PS:

Following [Haller Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5635941/haller-patrick)'s advice, modifying the project structure eliminated the original error message.

```
yolov3/
├──  yolov3/
|    ├── __init__.py
|    ├── models/
|    |   ├── __init__.py
|    |   ├── liba1.py
|    |   ├── liba2.py
|    |   ├── liba3.py
|    ├── utils/
|    |   ├── __init__.py
|    |   ├── libb1.py
|    |   ├── libb2.py
|    |   ├── libb3.py
|    └── weights/
|        └──  libc1.py
|
└── setup.py
```

But a message in a deeper folder level appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Code/Project/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from yolov3.detect import get_detections_from_single_frame as get_detections
  File "/home/user/Code/Project/Detection/yolov3/yolov3/detect.py", line 9, in <module>
    from models.experimental import attempt_load
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a precise answer, you would have to provide the project structure of the package `yolov3`. But I guess the problem is that the package `yolov3`, does not include a module to build.

A minimal project structure has to look like this:

```
yolov3/
├── yolov3/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lib1.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── ...
├── setup.py
```

Important is the `__init__.py` file, so `yolov3` can be imported as a module. This worked for me.

For reference, here is a python package which uses this structure: https://github.com/gruns/icecream

Comment: It has indeed eliminated the error, but there seems to be another problem related to the project structure. I have added information related to the structure. Now I am getting the 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`.

Comment: Ah yes, that is because now all your imports inside of the module, also have to be module imports. 
You can either solve this with absolut imports:
`from yolov3 import models`  Or with relative: `from . import  models`
You can read more about it here: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/